# Downloading file using href

Tags: java, jsp, href

I am using eclipse IDE and Apache tomcat server version 6 to develop a web application. I want to download file using href option. I created a folder called pdfs inside the WebContent folder in my project in workspace. I copied all the pdf files iniside the pdfs folder.

Now when I want download the file, I am not able to download and it says 404 error. here is my code

`<body>
<a href="pdfs/file1.pdf">Download</a>
</body>`

Could some one tell me where I am making mistake.

Comment: Can you edit in what kind of application server and technologies(portal/framework/how you build the project/etc..) are you using, please?

Comment: Check your directory permissions.

Comment: Make sure to have a folder caled pdfs in the root of your web application and that file1.pdf exists in that folder.

Comment: Search on Google there are lots of example on it.

Comment: @Dropout I have edited my question..please take a look.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I have checked and that folder has full controls of administrative. But it works only within internal browser of eclipse if copy the same pdf files in some other location part from C

Comment: Is that the specific code in your application or are you using some scriptlet or taglib like JSTL?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It is not specific but basic href code in JSP

Comment: So that's the rendered HTML. Please provide the exact piece of JSP you use.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have posted my entire JSP code in my edited version. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Please try using a relative url, for example "../pdfs/file1.pdf" or similar.